# Cant center div

Tags: css, html, center

I cannot center the div with id="a" [on this site](http://lessn.me)

I have tried everything. If anybody wants me to, I can copy and paste my code in jsFiddle.

Comment: Never a bad idea to make a jsfiddle example for something of this nature.

Comment: Easily fixed, doesn't really need one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to the div with `id="a"` `style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;"` using inline styling, or apply this in your CSS stylesheet:

```
#a { 
    style="display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto;"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to center the elements in the browser window. If so, you need to wrap the elements in a 'container' DIV. Then set a `width` and `margin: 0 auto;` on it.

```
<div id="container">
  //Page elements here
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `margin: 0 auto`

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/yEXWT/)